# How to resolve this general Matlab matrix trick

Tags: matlab, matrix, transpose

Just a general Matlab matrix trick I am trying to understand? What does this line really mean logically?

```
S=X*X';
```

What does S accomplish if I transpose any generic matrix against itself? 
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `X` is a general `NxM` matrix, then `S=X*X'` is the sum of the outer products of each of the columns of `X` with its transpose. In other words, writing `X=[x1,x2,...,xM]`, `S` can be written as

```
S = ∑_i x_i * x_i'
```

The resulting matrix `S` is non-negative definite (i.e., eigenvalues are not negative).

If you consider each element in a column of `X` as a random variable (total `N`), and the different columns as `M` independent observations of the `N` dimensional random vector, then `S` is the `NxN` [sample covariance matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_matrix) (differing by a constant normalization, depending on your conventions) of the rows. Similarly, `S=X'*X` gives you the `MxM` covariance matrix of the columns.

---

Now if you start restricting the generality and assign special properties to `X`, then you'll start seeing patterns emerge for the structure of `S`. For example, if `X` is square, has real entries and is [orthogonal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_matrix), then `S=I`, the identity matrix. If `X` is square, has complex entries and is a [unitary matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_matrix), then `S` is then again, the identity matrix.

Without knowing the exact circumstances in which this was used in your program, I would assume that they were calculating the covariance matrix.

Comment: I do believe identity matrix is correct for this context Thanks to all including Yoda

Comment: @yoda - this is a well-written and helpful explanation, but I think in a couple of places you've got columns and rows confused. `S=X*X'` is the covariance matrix of the _rows_ of `X`; `X'*X` is the covariance matrix of the columns. Perhaps a quick edit could correct that.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example to show how this is related to the covariance matrix (as [@yoda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8220884/how-to-resolve-this-general-matlab-matrix-trick/8220928#8220928) explained):

```
X = randn(5,3);                     %# 3 column-vectors each of dimension=5
X0 = bsxfun(@minus, X, mean(X,2));  %# zero-centered

C = (X0*X0') ./ (size(X0,2)-1)      %'# sample covariance matrix
CC = cov(X')                        %'# should return the same result
```